# df -h Size - User != Avail

Tags: unix, centos, df

When I run `df -h` I get the following

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             809G  753G   14G  99% /
```

But Size - Used is not even close to Avail (809-753 = 56 and it shows 14)

How is that possible? How much space do I really have left?

Answer (score 2):

Usually there is some "reserved" space for superuser (sic), and then there is the fs overhead (i-node tables, etc). Depends on the filesystem.

ext2/3/4 has a default reserve of 5% for uid0 (`-m`)
depending on the usage-type (`-T`) i-node space is pre-allocated - see `df -ih`

I'd say the 14G are really available, but there may be 40G of reserve and say 100MB of i-nodes, which would pretty much add up. #ymmw

Comment: 40GB of reserve, what does that mean?

Comment: only the root can use it.

Comment: if you have the ext4 fs, check `man tune2fs` where the reserved space can be changed (i-nodes can be set only while formatting)

Comment: Is that something I can verify / configure? I'm pretty sure a couple of days ago it did add up (and didn't change any config)

Comment: sometimes the filesystem totals lag if a big amount of files and/or space is freed up. But not couple of days...